# Length of a partition being equal to the length of the interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

My question concerns regarding the following lemma:-

"***Lemma:-*** $[a_1,b_1)$,$[a_2,b_2)$ ... be a partition of an interval $[a,b)$, that is the intervals $[a_1,b_1)$,$[a_2,b_2)$ ... are disjoint and
                         $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,b_n)=[a,b) $$
Then  $$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(b_n - a_n)=b-a$$

The proof is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-QDwHPzZ6oNQdH6mxxLunp7u5hmtEa6D/view?usp=sharing).
My doubts are as follows:-

1. Why can't we directly conclude it as follows:-if the semi open sets
   are of the form$[x_n,x_{n+1})$, then the sum
           $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_{n})=b-a$ as seen from [this
           document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GlWDYTiZLNfdiQhGYhCEBZRear2zrgLC/view?usp=sharing).

   2.Also in the proof it is said that we assume a non-decreasing sequence of elements of S. But why is this so? As per the proof upto
       this part we only know that there is atleast one element but how do
       we know there is more than one and also that they form a converging
       sequence of elements to s?(the supremum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in the statement you are considering here, it is not given that $a_{i+1}=b_i$ for any $i$. So the reasoning of your alternative proof cannot be applied directly. If you had a finite partition you could rearrange, but with countably many this is not so easy.
2. if you know a nonempty set has a lub, you can always find a nondecreasing sequence in that set converging to the lub, almost by definition (you should  check that). If the set has only one element, then the sequence is constant, but so what?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. But one thing- could you please clarify as to what goes wrong when we consider the telescoping of the infinite sum(as given in 1. of your answer)?

Comment: @CilmoVilde I tried to address this already: telescoping works when the intervals are ordered like in your second example - that is because $a_{i+1} = b_i$. If you write down the first term ($b_0 - a_0$) and you want to cancel the $b_0$ with the next term, you need that $a_1 = b_0$. Of course you could try to find $a_k$ such that $a_k = b_0$, but it is not clear, that such an $a_k$ exists, if your collection of intervals is not finite. And even if it would exist, the reasoning would become messy.

Comment: thanks a lot @thomas